# Using MySQL Shell to dump db into s3 bucket giving XML error when JSON is returned

Tags: amazon-s3, mysql-shell

I am trying to use Mysql Shell to do an instance dump and write the resulting data to an s3 bucket. However, the shell reports an error when it connects to s3, stating it cannot parse the returned XML:

```
Failed to parse XML response: Error=XML_ERROR_PARSING_TEXT ErrorID=8 (0x8) Line number=1
{"bucket":"phx-prod","keyCount":1,"maxKeys":1,"versions":false,"prefix":"db-backup\/daily\/","delimiter":"\/","truncated":true,"results":[{"size":1598218416,"lastModified":1680331040164,"version":"a70b9640-d057-11ed-92ba-58c497a6c912","key":"db-backup\/daily\/dbs-Fri.sql.xz.enc"}]}
```

I simplified the response JSON some - but the point is that the response (which is valid and shows a successful connection) is not XML at all.

What is more, based on [the s3 docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output-format.html) it is not even *possible* to get s3 to return XML data. I cannot find any s3 options in the [MySQL Shell docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-utilities-dump-instance-schema.html) to tell the shell to use a JSON parser for the response.

How do I get the shell to expect JSON from the s3 instance?